# How to overdrive FLASH MESSAGE default of cakePHP

Tags: cakephp

For `$this->Session->setFlash('this is message','flash_error');` you
only need to create `flash_error.ctp` in the elements folder to have a different look.

But what is with `$this->Session->setFlash('this is message')`? How do I modify the standard layout? I don't want to modify it with css or javascript.

Answer (score 13):

Laheab answer is right. But you can override it using the `AppController` `beforeRender` function. In your `app/app_controller.php` write this function :

```
function beforeRender(){
    if ($this->Session->check('Message.flash')) {
        $flash = $this->Session->read('Message.flash');

        if ($flash['element'] == 'default') {
            $flash['element'] = 'flash_error';
            $this->Session->write('Message.flash', $flash);
        }
    }
}
```

It will override the 'default' flash element with 'flash_error'. Then in `app/views/elements` create `flash_error.ctp`

Comment: Thanks for this. I had to fix it a bit though. The final line should actually read: $this->Session->write('Message.flash', $flash);

Comment: A wandering moderator should edit answer to reflect above comment.

Answer (score 2):

The HTML for flash messages is output in the flash method of the SessionHelper class. I find the easiest way to achieve what you're trying to do is to override the core SessionHelper class. To do this

Copy **lib/Cake/View/Helper/SessionHelper.php** to **app/View/Helper/SessionHelper.php**

Cake will now use the SessionHelper class in your app as opposed to it's own. Now you can update the flash method to output the HTML you want. On line 136, you'll see this:

```
$out = '<div id="' . $key . 'Message" class="' . $class . '">' . $message . '</div>';
```

As an example, if I'm using Twitter Bootstrap, I'll update this line to be:

```
$out = '<div class="alert fade in"><a class="close" data-dismiss="alert" href="#">&times;</a>' . $message . '</div>';
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [CakePHP book entry on flash()](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1467/flash):

```
<?= $session->flash(); ?>
```

in a view file outputs:

```
<div id='flashMessage' class='message'>My Message</div>
```

So there is nothing to override but the CSS for this id in cake.generic.css.

Hope I understood the question correctly. =)

Comment: No, i want create something like flash_error.ctp in elements folder that overdrive default message of cakephp, my app is very many 
$this->Session->setFlash('this is message')

Comment: What part do you exactly want to override? The text or the style?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot override default HTML for a flash message. What I did is: created the following  function in app_controller:

```
protected function _f($message, $url=false) {
    $this->Session->setFlash($message,'message');
    if($url) $this->redirect($url);
}
```

Created my own message.ctp template in views/elements.

Then used the _f function inc all controllers like this:

```
$this->_f('This is a flash message','/page_to_redirect/');
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to create a default.ctp in elements folder?

That might be what you wanted?