# CakePHP - Changing default Flash layout

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I know that I can replace the flash markup by creating something like `custom_flash.ctp` in Elements folder and call it like:

```
$this->Session->setFlash('Hello', custom_flash)
```

But how can I use custom layout when not adding the second parameter?

```
$this->Session->setFlash('Hello')
```

I thought I can replace the default by having a file named `default.ctp` inside Elements folder. But I can't.

I want to keep the code as short as possible. That's why I'm looking a way to do this

Any solution? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to create your Component:

```
class MySessionComponent extends Session {
    public function setFlash($message) {
         return $this->setFlash($message, 'custom_flash');
    }
}
```

and than in your controller just use:

```
public $components = array('MySession');
$this->MySession->setFlash('Hello');
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but changing the `Session` object will make me change all the default code from `cake bake`.

Comment: No, it will not. All "baked" code that use $this->Session->someFunction() will be executed from Cake core. All $this->MySession->someFunction() will be executed from your class (that extend Session class).

Comment: See this for a better answer. Look at the one that is not accepted. It talks about aliasing. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11649285/how-to-extend-or-override-functionality-methods-of-a-cakephp-core-helper

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3590097/how-to-overdrive-flash-message-default-of-cakephp).

We need to add this codes in `app/Controller/AppController.php`

```
function beforeRender(){
    if ($this->Session->check('Message.flash')) {
        $flash = $this->Session->read('Message.flash');

        if ($flash['element'] == 'default') {
            $flash['element'] = 'fileNameOfYourCustomFlash';
            $this->Session->write('Message.flash', $flash);
        }
    }
}
```

It basically add `element` parameter in `flash` when it doesn't exist yet.

Comment: this is much better than the accepted answer. Creating a whole component just to hardcode a new default, then having to deal with two different yet basically identical Session managers, when the whole thing could be achieved by just adding a second parameter to the setFlash... Just messy overkill

Answer (score 0):

This is explained on the cakephp website [here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/session.html)

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.