# Cakephp 2.0 Logout with flash message

Tags: php, cakephp, logout, flash-message

My Logout function is working very well with only return $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());.

But how could I make a logout function with a Flash message? I tried this function. It doesn't work. I'm always login and it doesn't show me message:(

```
public function logout() {
    if ($this->Auth->user('logged_in')) {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('you are logout'), 'default', array('class' => 'alert alert-success'));
        return $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
    } else {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('you aren\'t logout, Please, try again'), 'default', array('class' => 'alert alert-danger'));
    }
}
```

Comment: `$this->Auth->user('logged_in')` Why are you not using the official and documented approach via AuthComponent? This custom approach is very uncommon and easily breakable probably. And stuff like login() logout() might also not like it. Please read the docs on how to do it right.

Answer (score 1):

Inside the [documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/sessions.html#creating-notification-messages]) says that if you want to create a custom message do by in /app/View/Elements. If you want your personalized message is not the way to go.

in your
/app/View/Elements/defaul.ctp

```
$this->Session->setFlash(__('you are logout'), 'default', array('class' => 'alert alert-success'));
```

afte in your cont roller

```
public function logout() {
    if ($this->Auth->user('logged_in')) {
        $this->Session->setFlash('something', 'default');
        return $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
    } else {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('you aren\'t logout, Please, try again'), 'default', array('class' => 'alert alert-danger'));
    }
}
```

you could also do it through a [component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16827171/cakephp-changing-default-flash-layout)